# Poetry of the stars

Tags: mathematics, word, visual, graph-theory

Prof. Levenshtein is meant to be teaching us astronomy, but they fancy themselves as a poet. Can you figure out the name they've given to each star?

[image: Constellation]

Comment: @JLee Why did you edit my question?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The names are given based on

> [Levenshtein distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance#:%7E:text=Informally%2C%20the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between,considered%20this%20distance%20in%201965.) as suggested by the name of the lecturer. Each edge between two words indicates a Levenshtein distance of 1.

So the names of the stars are

> Red: clue

> Orange: cue

> Yellow: cut

> Purple: but

> Green: bit

> Brown: bid